# does semantic ui framework support rtl languages?

Tags: css, frameworks

how to make semantic ui framework "right-to-left" supported ? is there 
anyway to make it rtl support in installing steps or not ?

Answer (score 6):

You can enable RTL support under the following scenarios:

## 1. Fresh Installation

go to the document root of your project and install semantic-ui through npm

> npm install semantic-ui --save

modify **semantic.json** file in document root to enable right to left support as following:

> "rtl": true

in your terminal change directory to **semantic** directory

> cd semantic/

run the following gulp task to build all files and save it to destination folder

> gulp build

gulp will auto-detect the RTL support and build the RTL version of css files and save them in dist folder, now a very important final step is to reference the RTL version of semantic-ui css file in your **index.html** or web page as following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.rtl.css">
```

---

## 2. Existing Installation

in your terminal change directory to **semantic** directory

> cd semantic/

Clean the destination folder using the gulp task provided by semantic-ui framework

> gulp clean

modify **semantic.json** file in document root to enable right to left support as following:

> "rtl": true

run the following gulp task to build all files and save it to destination folder

> gulp build

gulp will auto-detect the RTL support and build the RTL version of css files and save them in dist folder.

Now you need to replace the reference in your html page from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="semantic/dist/semantic.rtl.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

**first:**
navigate to your project root and then fire: **npm install semantic-ui --save**
and wait for all done.

**second:**
edit *semantic.json* file (located in project root) and change ***"rtl": false*** to ***"rtl": true***

**third:**
navigate to semantic dir(cd semantic) and fire: **gulp build** and then **gulp watch**.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you where not installing it by npm and gulp, you may get the rtl versions from [RTLCSS website](https://rtlcss.com/cdn/css-frameworks/semantic-ui/index.html). They also provide a cdn, or you can download the css and js file and use them in your sources.