# how to change semantic-ui menu to RTL

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

i try to change semantic-ui  menu component to right to left , but semantic-ui use flex for menu and any other component and i try this menu to right

```
<div class="ui secondary menu">
  <a class="active item">
    Home
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    Messages
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    Friends
  </a>
</div>
```

when insert "left" class for first "a" tag menu float to right , but first tag still in the left of

```
<div class="ui secondary menu">
  <a class="active item left">
    Home
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    Messages
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    Friends
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694201/does-semantic-ui-framework-support-rtl-languages/33313254#33313254

Answer (score 2):

The best option is to use `dir` attribute in the HTML.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.0.1/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ui secondary menu" dir="rtl">
  <a class="active item">
    Home
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    Messages
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    Friends
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom class `.rtl` and use `flex-direction` to `row-reverse` which represents the menu from right to left.

```css
.rtl {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.0.1/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="ui secondary menu rtl">
  <a class="active item">
    Home
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    Messages
  </a>
  <a class="item">
    Friends
  </a>
</div>
```